# Error: objects can be used in same thread

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm working on a project very similar to this one: [GitHub](https://github.com/sixhobbits/python-telegram-tutorial/tree/master/part2)

I have a class:

```py
class DBfunctions:
    def __init__(self, dbname = '../example.db'):
        self.debname = dbname
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    def search_db(self, telegram_id):
        telegram_id = (telegram_id,)
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?;'
        row = self.conn.execute(sql,telegram_id)
        return row
    def newuser_db(self, tele_id, name, nick):
        par = (tele_id, name, nick, 0)
        sql = 'INSERT INTO user VALUES(?,?,?,?);'
        self.conn.execute(sql, par)
        self.conn.commit()
```

than i have the main project:

```py
from file import DBfunctions

db = DBfunction()

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext): #befor edit: somethingtodo
    flag = db.search_db(update.effective_user.id)    # here problems start    
    if flag == None:
        db.newuser_db(update.effective_user.id, update.effective_user.first_name, update.effective_user.username)
        update.message.reply_text(
            'Hi!',
            reply_markup=markup,
        )
    else:
        update.message.reply_text(
            'Hey! Welcome back!',
            reply_markup=markup,
        )


def main():
    db.setup() # this function is to create tables if not exist yet
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    # other function but nothing correlated

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And than the error appears:

```
File "filefolder/file.py", line 29, in search_db
    row = self.conn.execute(sql,telegram_id)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 15004 and this is thread id 11036.
```

I can't figure out what i can do to fix it... and don't understand what is different from the project that I find on github (linked)

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The error indicates that the object is being used in a different thread than it was created in, and errors are usually correct. You must be using multithreading somewhere. How is `somethingtodo` used? Are you passing it as a callback somewhere?

Comment: @Carcigenicate okay, i think now is reproducible

Comment: `dispatcher` must be running the callbacks in another thread. Judging by the error, you'd need to either create the `db` object inside the thread that `dispatcher` dispatches to, or communicate back to the main thread from the callback and run `execute` outside of the callback. You could create your own side thread, create the `db` inside of that thread, then use a `queue` or something to send `update.effective_user.id` to your thread from the callback to do the lookup. I can see that being a pain though.